# Command timeouts in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a Julia script that repeatedly calls a C++ program to perform an optimization. The C++ program writes a text file, then I have Julia read the results and decide what to do next. The problem is that occasionally (maybe 1 in 1000+ times) the C++ program freezes (the optimization probably gets stuck), and my entire script hangs indefinitely, making it very difficult for the script to make it through all necessary program calls. Is there a way I can add a timeout, so that if the program has not finished within 10 minutes I can restart with a new guess value?

Simplified example:

```
for k = 1:10
    run(`program inputs`)
end
```

Desired:

```
max_runtime = 10*60 # 10 minutes
for k = 1:10
    run(`program inputs`,max_runtime)
end
```

Alternative:

```
max_runtime = 10*60 # 10 minutes
for k = 1:10
    deadline(function,max_runtime)
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like:

```
max_runtime = 10*60 # 10 minutes
for k = 1:10
    proc = spawn(`program inputs`)
    timedwait(() -> process_exited(proc), max_runtime)
    if process_running(proc)
        kill(proc)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm having trouble getting this to run. When I get to the `timedwait` call, I get an error message: `ERROR: wrong number of arguments in anonymous at ... in timedwait at multi.jl:1552 in anonymous at no file:285` etc.` I'm not very competent with anonymous functions yet, is there an issue there?

Comment: Playing around a little more, I found that it works when I change `x` to `()`. I'm not sure exactly why this is, but thanks again for the help!

Comment: Oops,I did screw up that anonymous function call.  I should have tested my answer but was in a hurry and wanted to get you something helpful sooner rather than later.  My apologies and thanks for catching the problem